# Push notification when a new post published on a WordPress website

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have connected my app with Google Firebase. I'm just doing a WebView app that pushes notification when a new post is created on a WordPress website.

I'm running WP REST API v2 and filter fields on my website. I just need it to check if new post is created on website and notify the app user. Do you have any tutorials or something to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I just found this plugin that could help you achieve this, all you have to do is specify your API Key and Topic which your app would subscribe to, to receive notifications.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-firebase-push-notification/

If you'd like to make some customization or see how it works under the hood, here's the link to the plugin code on github.

https://github.com/Clintal/wp-firebase-push-notification/